# Strong Name Keys on Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Attempting to use http://code.google.com/p/moq/ in VS2010 running Administrator on a Win7 virtual machine.

I'm getting an ArgumentException:  Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair

Have changed permissions here to be Full Control for Everyone

C:\Users\dave\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

I can't get any projects that use Moq to run tests (eg NerdDinner)

Any thoughts?

[alt text http://www.programgood.net/screen.jpg](http://www.programgood.net/screen.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but from Ayende's blog:

Most often the issue is file permission one. And the troublesome directory is (drum roll): "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA"

The default permission for this directory are:

cacls MachineKeys
MachineKeys Everyone:(special access:)
READ_CONTROL
SYNCHRONIZE
FILE_GENERIC_READ
FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
FILE_READ_DATA
FILE_WRITE_DATA
FILE_APPEND_DATA
FILE_READ_EA
FILE_WRITE_EA
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

BUILTIN\Administrators:F

Administrators has full control, everyone has had read/write access, but not delete access.

Comment: Thanks heads5150 - have tried this.. now will give this a good try to get working again.

Comment: Thanks you were correct.. http://www.programgood.net/2010/07/05/ArgumentExceptionWasUnhandledByUserCodeUnableToObtainPublicKeyForStrongNameKeyPair.aspx